# Use argument passed to when in branch condition in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have some code that roughly looks like this:

```
val myObject = myObjectRepository.findById(myObjectId);    
when {        
    matchesSomething(myObject) -> doSomethingWithMyObject(myObject)
    matchesSomethingElse(myObject) -> doSomethingElseWithMyObject(myObject)
    else -> log.warn("No match, aborting");
}
```

While this works I would think that the following (which doesn't work) would be an improvement if I only need access to `myObject` inside the scope of `when`:

```
when(myObjectRepository.findById(myObjectId)) { myObject ->
    matchesSomething(myObject) -> doSomethingWithMyObject(myObject)
    matchesSomethingElse(myObject) -> doSomethingElseWithMyObject(myObject)
    else -> log.warn("No match, aborting"); 
}
```

The error I get here is:

> Unresolved reference: myObject

Can you do something like this in Kotlin and if so how? If not, is there a particular reason for why this shouldn't be allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression), the proper syntax would be

```
val myObject = myObjectRepository.findById(myObjectId);
when {
    matchesSomething(myObject) -> doSomethingWithMyObject(myObject)
    matchesSomethingElse(myObject) -> doSomethingElseWithMyObject(myObject)
    else -> log.warn("myObject not found, aborting")
}
```

Or, to actually match what your first snippet does:

```
val myObject = myObjectRepository.findById(myObjectId);
when(myObject) {
    null -> log.warn("myObject not found, aborting");
    matchesSomething(myObject) -> doSomethingWithMyObject(myObject)
    matchesSomethingElse(myObject) -> doSomethingElseWithMyObject(myObject) 
}
```

Comment: You're right of course, but my main point is rather about the scope of "myObject" that I only need access to inside the when-statement. I've updated the question to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: @Johan I think this actually answer the question. `when` is an [expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression) in Kotlin. You can't achieve what you want to try according to its [syntax](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#when).

Comment: *is there a particular reason for why this shouldn't be allowed?*: yes: it's not supported by the kotlin compiler. That's just not how the when expression works.

Comment: I get it now, sorry for the noise. Maybe I should remove the question?

Comment: No, you shouldn't. It's been asked and answered. And maybe it'll help someone else later. No reason to delete it.

Comment: @Johan It may be useful to the others, as long as it is not duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful about the syntax. In a `while` we use an arrow `->` which has nothing to do with lambdas. I think this is what you were trying in your example.

The only valid syntax for `when` is this:

```
when (x) {
   1 -> print("x == 1")
   2 -> print("x == 2")
   else -> { // Note the block
       print("x is neither 1 nor 2")
   }
```

On the left side of the arrow `->` you declare what the object (x) is being **matched** against, whereas on the right side you tell what will be executed in that case. Read about this [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression).

In your example you tried to chain multiple `->` which does not work.

Comment: When looking at the syntax _carefully_ as you implied it does indeed makes sense. Feel kind of ashamed for the noise now.

Comment: No need to be! Keep coding ;-)

Comment: Thanks :) With the risk of embarrassing myself even further I _think_ what I'm after is something like a "when-let" (i.e. something similar to "if let" in Swift but with the semantics of Kotlin's "when").

Answer (score 1):

This is supported as of Kotlin 1.3. It's referred to as "[Capturing when subject in a variable](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew13.html#capturing-when-subject-in-a-variable)" and looks like this (taken from their documentation):

```
fun Request.getBody() =
        when (val response = executeRequest()) {
            is Success -> response.body
            is HttpError -> throw HttpException(response.status)
        }
```